# How to add a folder to a remote hosts PATH using a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I'd like to automate the process of syncing a local `~/bin` folder to a remote host, and adding that folder to my remote shell's path. I've got the syncing part done, but am not sure how to automate adding the folder to my remote shell's `$PATH`.

This way I could always work on my shell scripts on my local machine, and if I have to connect to a new machine and start working on it, I could just run a local script to sync my ~/bin folder to the remote machine, and then run scripts on the remote host easily all the time.

**So how can I ensure that my `~/bin` path is added to the `$PATH` of the remote host, so the next time I login, the `$PATH` is set correctly?**

I'd like this to be done automatically from my shell script.

EDIT: I'd prefer not to sync a `.bashrc`, but append to an existing file if need be by adding something to the end using a shell script.

Comment: Also sync an appropriate `~/.bashrc` and such as well as `~/bin` ?

Comment: Since adding to `$PATH` is a one-off it would probably be easier just to edit `.bash_profile` / `.bashrc` and have done with it.

Comment: I can do that, but I have to connect to lots of different machines all the time, and would like to automate the entire process, including the PATH addition.

Comment: Add `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH` (or some such) to `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` as part of your standard configuration. Once per host. Job done. It doesn't matter that `$HOME/bin` might not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach that would work is just appending to the end of the bashrc rather than syncing it.

```
echo "PATH=\$PATH:~/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
```

This will add ~/bin onto the PATH variable.

In order to get this on a remote host you just need to call ssh first. You can use a for loop if you have lots of hosts.

```
for host in host1 host2 host3;do
    ssh user@$host echo "PATH=\$PATH:~/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
done
```

Comment: I ended up adding a grep around it to ensure it wasnt in the file already, and putting that in a script called ***path_add_bin_to_path***, which is like the following: ```if ! grep -q PATH:~/bin ~/.bashrc; then
  echo "PATH=\$PATH:~/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
fi```

I then called that script from my machine using ```ssh user@host ~/bin/path_add_bin_to_path```, which I did in a script right after my syning operation, which is basically ```rsync -avrz --progress ~/bin/ -e ssh user@host:~/bin     ```